# How to replace one digit in a number in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to change group of numbers to another one.

*Now:*

```
PRACTICE_ID (FK)         GROUP_ID     ...
0_4_200_400_0.5          4
0_4_300_300_0.5          4
0_4_400_700_0.5          4
0_5_200_400_0.5          5
0_5_900_400_0.5          5
0_5_650_400_0.5          5
```

*Should be:*

```
PRACTICE_ID (FK)         GROUP_ID     ...
*0_5_200_400_0.5         4
0_5_300_300_0.5          4
0_5_400_700_0.5          4
*0_5_200_400_0.5         5
0_5_900_400_0.5          5
0_5_650_400_0.5          5
```

I use the query to reach the target:

```
UPDATE CUSTOM_PRACTICE
SET PRACTICE_ID = REPLACE(PRACTICE_ID, '0_4', '0_5')
WHERE GROUP_ID = 4
```

In this case I cannot duplicate values. I was trying to use `NOT EXISTS` clause but didn't get result

How can I rewrite all values which have not duplicate? Like this:

```
PRACTICE_ID (FK)         GROUP_ID     ...
0_4_200_400_0.5          4
0_5_300_300_0.5          4
0_5_400_700_0.5          4
0_5_200_400_0.5          5
0_5_900_400_0.5          5
0_5_650_400_0.5          5
```

Comment: You want the * as a prefix in first and fourth row ?
If so, why ?

Comment: Just do 2 queries : UPDATE then DELETE

Comment: Why are you asking this? What is the *real* problem you want to solve? This is a string, not a number. Adding a *prefix* to a foreign key ID will break the relation between that row and any related rows. Finally, using such a string as an ID is *very* unusual. Are you trying to stuff other fields into the ID perhaps? Use the ID to represent other values, flags etc?

Comment: @PraneetNadkar No it's like highlight. I don't want to add the symbol to records

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just want to replace all settings from one group of activities to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE CUSTOM_PRACTICE
SET PRACTICE_ID = REPLACE(PRACTICE_ID, '0_4', '0_5')
WHERE GROUP_ID = 4 AND REPLACE(PRACTICE_ID, '0_4', '0_5') NOT IN
   (SELECT PRACTICE_ID FROM CUSTOM_PRACTICE)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a very convenient function for this called `STUFF()`.  One way of doing what you want uses `NOT EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE CUSTOM_PRACTICE
    SET PRACTICE_ID = STUFF(PRACTICE_ID, 3, 1, '5')
    WHERE PRACTICE_ID LIKE '0_4%' AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM CUSTOM_PRACTICE CP2
                      WHERE CP2.PRACTICE_ID = STUFF(PRACTICE_ID, 3, 1, '5') AND
                            STUFF(PRACTICE_ID, 3, 1, '5')
                     );
```

Note that `REPLACE(PRACTICE_ID, '0_4', '0_5')` does not really do what yo want, because:

```
REPLACE('0_4_200_400_0.5', '0_4', '0_5')
```

returns:

```
'0_5_200_500_0.5'
```

not:

```
'0_4_200_400_0.5'
```

However, I think I like using an updatable CTE, because the logic only appears in one place:

```
with toupdate as (
      select cp.*
             (case when practice_id like '0_4%' then stuff(practice_id, 3, 1, '5')
                   else practice_id
              end) as new_practice_id
      from custom_practice cp
     )
update t
    set practice_id = new_practice_id
    from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by new_practice_id) as cnt
          from toupdate
         )
    where practice_id <> new_practice_id and cnt = 1;
```